# Diffing two big text files

Tags: performance, diff, large-files

I have two big files (6GB each). They are unsorted, with linefeeds (`\n`) as separators. How can I diff them? It should take under 24h.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The most obvious answer is just to use the diff command and it is probably a good idea to add the --speed-large-files parameter to it.

```
diff --speed-large-files a.file b.file
```

You mention unsorted files so maybe you need to sort the files first

```
sort a.file > a.file.sorted
sort b.file > b.file.sorted
diff --speed-large-files a.file.sorted b.file.sorted
```

you could save creating an extra output file by piping the 2nd sort output direct into diff

```
sort a.file > a.file.sorted
sort b.file | diff --speed-large-files a.file.sorted -
```

Obviously these will run best on a system with plenty of available memory and you will likely need plenty of free disk space too.

It wasn't clear from your question whether you have tried these before. If so then it would be helpful to know what went wrong (took too long etc.). I have always found that
the stock sort and diff commands tend to do at least as well as custom commands unless
there are some very domain specific properties of the files that make it possible to
do things differently.

Comment: +1. You can omit all temporary files with named pipes. Use `mkfifo` to create `[ab].file.sorted` before using them as output for `sort`. Put both `sort`s with `&` in the background and use the both piped as filenames for diff.

Comment: @krissi You can also accomplish the same effect using this syntax: `diff <(command 1) <(command 2)`

Comment: Thanks worked. I needed a couple of GB of memory thought but a 16GB Amazon EC2 instance fixed it :)

Comment: If someone like me wonders why `<(cmd1) <(cmd2)` syntax works (as it sounds like redirecting standard input twice!), try `echo hello <(cmd1) <(cmd2)`. You'll see something like `hello /dev/fd/63 /dev/fd/62` which suddenly makes it clear ;)

Comment: Note that diff easily runs out of memory if you have really large files. For creating patches/deltas at least there are some other options: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77259/27186 though perhaps not for visually inspecting changes

Comment: In my experience, the `--speed-large-files` option does not help if you do not have enough RAM. Also, pre-sorting is not helpful if you have a multi-line record structure you wish to preserve. The options referred to above (by @unhammer) are interesting, but the output from `rdiff` and `bsdiff` is rather binary. Installing `bdiff` from the Heirloom Toolbox looks like a dauning task (requires Heirloom devtools, extinct header files, …). Is it really worth the effort? Are there other alternatives?

Comment: For large files with very few differences, where you want to visually inspect the differences, I use this ugly hack: https://github.com/unhammer/diff-large-files – it works for that specific purpose, when `diff` would otherwise run out of memory. (If anyone is wondering how `sort` manages to not run out of RAM, check the size of your /tmp folder while you're sorting that 10GB file … wouldn't it be nice if `diff` could do the same thing :).)

Comment: Got a tip via https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13985216 – just `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Arkanosis/Arkonf/master/tools-src/bdiff.c` and `gcc -Wno-long-long bdiff.c -o bdiff`. For my test case at least, with few differences over large files, it uses zero memory!

Comment: @MichaelMrozek you should put your command as an answer.

Comment: Thanks @unhammer and @ChristianPietsch - I was trying to `diff` two 5GB binary files on an 8GB machine and it kept responding with `Killed`. In my case, I used `split` to split each file into 1GB chunks, then ran each pair of chunks through `diff`. All I wanted to see was whether they were the same or not, so that was good enough for me.

Answer (score 10):

Sorting the inputs and telling the `diff` program it's inputs are sorted would provide a massive speed up.  I don't know of any `diff` with an option like that but `comm` assumes sorted input and will be much quicker if it does enough for your purposes.

Comment: `comm` worked great for this, never heard of it before but apparently its in coreutils.

Answer (score 1):

The `bdiff` tool can work on unsorted files much larger than the computer's RAM.

Use these steps once, to download and compile `bdiff` before using it the first time:

```bash
wget https://github.com/Arkanosis/Arkonf/raw/master/tools-src/bdiff.c && \
  gcc -Wformat=0 -Wno-long-long bdiff.c -o bdiff && \
  rm bdiff.c
```

To run `bdiff` and compare 2 files:

```bash
./bdiff a.file b.file
```

You might find it helpful to redirect the `bdiff` output to a file.
Thanks to @unhammer for the suggestion and the link to the Git repository.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solutions on this page when I had problems using diff on some large text files a couple of days ago, but didn't find anything that worked for me, so I wrote a file comparison program specifically to handle large text files.  It seemed only fair to return here and let you know it's available. I've only used it myself and I'd appreciate if anyone else having problems with large text files could try it and report if it works - or doesn't - for you too.  Code is at https://github.com/gtoal/bigfile-diff-compare