# Is there bdiff (1) in Linux?

Tags: diff, large-files

There is `bdiff(1)` command in Solaris, which allow you to `diff(1)` files with size bigger than your RAM size ([documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-7612/files-23/index.html)).

Is there something like that in Linux? I tried googling but I don't find which package has `bdiff` in Ubuntu.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/174283/how-to-diff-large-files-on-linux

Comment: possible duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2150/diffing-two-big-text-files

Answer (score 14):

[bdiff appears to be available](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ubdiff.htm) on Linux (at least as part of the [Heirloom Toolchest](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/tools.html)).

### diff

I would probably just use regular old diff with this switch however:

```
diff --speed-large-files bigfileA bigfileB
```

#### Why it doesn't work?

See comment by @EvanTeitelman, `--speed-large-files` doesn't affect how files are loaded into memory.

Can be demonstrated/confirmed not to work using the following command:

```
fallocate -l 10G testa; fallocate -l 10G testb && \
        diff --speed-large-files -a testa testb
```

### bsdiff

Hard to confirm this but I found a tool called [`bsdiff`](http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/) which derives from `bdiff`. I've confirmed that this tool is in Ubuntu, simply `apt-get install bsdiff`.

#### Why it might work?

Again thanks @EvanTeitelman in the comments, the `bsdiff` above is a diff tool for binary files. `bsdiff` is a binary diff tool and can deal with large files. It's unclear just how large. See the following links to a thread which discuss it's use.

- [bdiff/bsdiff: comprehensive performance measurements for large files [long, but nice graphics attached]](http://selenic.com/pipermail/mercurial/2007-September/014533.html)

### rdiff

I think you could also use [rdiff](http://librsync.sourcefrog.net/doc/rdiff.html) to do this as well. Rdiff is able to deal with very large files.

1. Create a signature of one file:

   ```
   rdiff signature A sigs.txt
   ```
2. Use generated signature file sigs.txt and the other big file B to create the delta:

   ```
   rdiff delta sigs.txt B deltaAB.txt
   ```
3. Delta contains all the info you need to recreate file B when you have just A and the delta file deltaAB.txt.

   To recreate B, run:

   ```
   rdiff patch A deltaAB.txt B
   ```

#### Why it works?

I found this blog post titled: [A Better diff Or What To Do When GNU diff Runs Out Of Memory ("diff: memory exhausted")](http://beerpla.net/2008/05/12/a-better-diff-or-what-to-do-when-gnu-diff-runs-out-of-memory-diff-memory-exhausted/), which reports that a rdiff of 4.5GB files only consumed ~66MB of RAM.

### lfhex

[lfhex](http://stoopidsimple.com/lfhex) is an application for viewing and editing files in hex, octal, binary, or ascii text. The main strength of lfhex is it's ability to work with files much larger than system memory. It's a GUI tool however.

#### screenshot

[image: ss of lfhex]![ss of lfhex]

### References

- [Comparison of diff tools - wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools)

Comment: Although this isn't always documented, GNU diff allows you to use `-H` as a synonym for `--speed-large-files`.

Comment: `bsdiff` is a binary diff tool, not a large-file diff tool.

Comment: I read that as well on several forums but it isn't documented in `man diff`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems as though the `--speed-large-files` flag doesn't affect the manner in which GNU diff loads files into memory. Try running `fallocate -l 10G testa; fallocate -l 10G testb && diff --speed-large-files -a testa testb` to confirm this. (Or take a look at the source code.)

Comment: Is it possible to turn the output of rdiff or bsdiff into a unified diff format? I've been searching for a solution to no avail :(

Comment: I managed to build `bdiff` from the Heirloom Toolchest after replacing `/sbin/sh` by `/bin/sh` in the makefiles. Now when I try to execute it in place, I get `bdiff: Can not execute '/usr/5bin/diff'`. Sorry, I do not want to install anything to `/usr/5bin/`. This is not a viable solution. The other options mentioned here do not work for me because I want to eyeball the differences as text.

Comment: PS: Surprisingly, `lfhex -c file1 file2` works well for me after setting View –> Editing base –> ASCII for both panes.