# Comparing two files with an easy readable GUI program?

Tags: diff, file-comparison, large-files

I would like to compare two large files that are not close to 1Gb in size.

`Kompare` crashes when the files load is large. I configured `Kompare` as in the photo below:

[image: Trying to configure it for large files]

I would like to present the differences in a way that `Kompare` does (i.e. clear and showing with colors and lines), manageable for people who are not familiar with `Terminal`.

I have also tried using the command:

```
diff --speed-large-files a.file b.file
```

As suggested [here:](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2150/diffing-two-big-text-files)

Is there a way to dump the output of diff into a file, so it can be read later by another program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to dump the output of diff into a file, so it can be read later by another program?

Yep!

```
diff --speed-large-files a.file b.file > diffoutput
```

This creates a file called diffoutput, and writes the output of `diff` to it.

> I would like to present the differences in a way that Kompare does (i.e. clear and showing with colors and lines), manageable for people who are not familiar with Terminal.

I don't think Kompare will work for this purpose. (Or, at least not directly.) I tried to diff two 3MB files, and it required 150 MB of memory. I assume that if I tried to diff two 1GB files, it would require about 50GB.

Here some ideas:

- Split the files up. `split -l 5000 filename` can split a file named filename into 5000 line chunks.
- Remove unimportant lines. Hypothetically, if you only cared about lines that had FOOBAR in them, you could run `grep FOOBAR input > output` and get only the lines that contained FOOBAR.
- Use some shell. This command:

  ```
  colordiff --suppress-common-lines -y file1.ext file2.ext | aha > test.html
  ```

  will diff two lines; apply coloring for the differing lines; remove common lines; display them side-by-side; and create an HTML file that can be opened in a web browser.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! I really appreciate it.
Note: Doing some research, I have found a program called Beyond Compare that does almost the same thing with large files as the solution you've proposed.

Comment: Chopping up the files will split some matches, and make others dissappear (into different pieces).